# Changing a pages "Title" changes it's name in the menu list

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a menu in Sharepoint. In that menu is a list of about 5 pages. When I go to these "sub" pages, I edit their properties and change their title. However, this also changes the link name in the menu which is undesirable since the client wants titles like "About us | Hey hey hey | etc" for SEO reasons. If anyone could help that'd be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, your client is worried about SEO on a Sharepoint site?  That means you're exposing Sharepoint to the whole world.  That's usually a no-no; it's really designed for Intranets, not the web as a whole.

Comment: @Borealid: You might consider sharing your opinion with several of the world's major corporations that use SharePoint as their Internet portals. http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=202

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your menu behavior is because you are using MOSS 2007 with publishing features enabled, and the Include Pages check box checked in your navigation settings (Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Manage Navigation).

If this is so, SharePoint automatically provides links for pages for use in your global and current navigation, giving you options to position the link or hide it, as you choose.

To have more flexibility with the presentation of the link, uncheck "Include Pages", and add links manually. The trade-off is the extra keystrokes for more flexibility.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info. We're using SharePoint 2010, but I don't see that link for "manage navigation". Though I do see one that says navigation by itself. I'll poke around and see if I can find that, thanks!

Comment: @Peterson: Great. I still have quite a bit to learn about how 2010 manages navigation. I've updated your tags to reflect the version.